# Django testing a form is valid when it contains a ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-unittest

I have the following test...

```
def test_contact_form(self):
    form_data = {'name': 'Reiss Johnson',
                 'email': 'reissjohnson@test.com',
                 '_type': 'General Enquiry',
                 'content': 'This is some content'}
    form = ContactForm(data=form_data)
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

This was originally passing as '_type' was a CharField, however it is now a ModelChoiceField & so does anybody know why this is failing? Im guessing im inputting the '_type' into the dictionary incorrectly now?

How could I get the above test to pass again?

My form is as so...

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
      name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
      email = forms.EmailField()
      content = forms.CharField()
      _type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=EnquiryType.objects.values_list('text', flat=True), empty_label=None)
```

Comment: What are the values for `EnquiryType`? `GeneralEnquiry` might not be a valid choices, meaning it doesn't match any of the values for the queryset.

Comment: currently I have 2 `EnquiryType` objects one has a `.text` attribute of 'General Enquiry' and the other has a 'Request A Call Back' `.text` attribute. Do I need to pass in the attribute or something?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.
To expand on Shang's answer:

Yes, it looks like using the primary key of the model you're referencing will work.

Here's what I did:

```
valid_pk = NameOfModel.objects.all()[0].pk 
# You may need to replace 0 with the right number.
form_data = {'name': 'Reiss Johnson',
             'email': 'reissjohnson@test.com',
             '_type': str(valid_pk),
             'content': 'This is some content'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you didn't understand what does `ModelChoiceField` do. It would generate a list of `id`(which is the Primary Key for that model) that corresponds to each object that the model has, so when you save, it saves the `id` as foreign key. You can't feed the form field with a `text`, which is only a field of model `EnquiryType`. Think about it, if you don't refer to the primary key of another table but `.text`, which object should the `ModelChoiceField` select? What if you create another object that has the same `text`?

The easy fix would change your test data with the `id` of the object that has `General Enquiry` as `.text`.